Is there a limit to the number of posts a Twitter account can receive from 3rd party apps?
Two different free tier user (A and B), each with his own app, posting tweets on account C, using api v2. 24 hour limit is now 17 for each app. So in 24h time they should be able to post together a total of at least 34 tweets per day. instead the max reached is a total of 17.
I checked the response “x-app-limit-24hour-remaining” header and found that the reason is that every time a tweet is posted by one of the 2 apps, the counter is decremented in both.
It seems that the target account C can receive a max. total of 17 posts/day by all applications posting on it, not 17 by each one of them. Can anyone explain if this is the way it supposed to work? I don’t think so.
As additional information, I’m using C# and the Tweetinvi library, one of those suggested by Twitter docs.
Thanks for any idea.
Mark

You are posting as account C Not A, nor B. The total will be 17. I spent days to figure out what is the problem and in the end, the total depend on the final account, whatever the number of the Apps connected to the account.
They are forcing the developers to subscribe to higher tiers.
Also the documentation is still says 50 not 17.
